# They are independent events. So why don't we simply multiply the two probability?

Tags: probability

[image: Question is]

While solving the first part of the question , I simply multiplied the given probabilities as I thought that they are independent events so we can multiply them. But my answer is wrong.
Please explain why so?

Comment: What *is* the first part of the question?  The picture is cut off.

Comment: Multiplying is the probability that *both* A and B solve it.  If that is the question then you are right.  If the question is one or the other solves it that is a completely different question (And note: the probability that one or the other solves it must be *higher* if both are attempting than if only one is attempting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The event that the problem is solved is not "A solved it AND B solved it".  It is "A solved it OR B solved it".

I would go about this as
$$
\begin{align*}
P(\text{solved})&=1-P(\text{not solved})\\
&=1-P(A\text{ fails}, B\text{ fails})\\
&=1-P(A\text{ fails})P(B\text{ fails})\\
&=1-\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{2}{3}\\
&=\frac{2}{3}.
\end{align*}
$$
Alternatively, you can note that
$$
P(\text{solved})=P(A,B)+P(A,\neg B)+P(\neg A, B)
$$
(where we use $A$ and $B$ to denote success of the respective people and $\neg A$ and $\neg B$ to denote failure). This will lead you to the same thing.

Comment: Thanks for your answer 